# Change ULS log path for multiple server farm

Tags: uls

On our Sharepoint 2013 on-premise environment, we have 2 WFE, 2APP and 1SQL structure. We are planning to switch the default log path (C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15) to another drive.

According to [Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748656.aspx) article, the change is quite straight forward. However it doesn't mention what would happen on multiple server environment. Let's say I switch to D:\LOGS. Do I need to make sure 2 WFE, 2 APP all have same path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to make sure WFE and APP servers all have that same path.

Comment: I notice the existing size of log files are different. May I know how SharePoint determine where to write the logs?

Comment: Internally SharePoint does load balancing, so it decides which WFE serves the actual user request (you might also have external load balancer doing this for you when it comes to WFEs) - events related to this request get written to the ULS log of that specific WFE. 

Same goes for APP servers, depending on which server a service is run, events are logged only to ULS of that server.